# Will the server handle two or more at the same time?

Tags: php

I have this code in PHP writing views to a text-file and just increasing the number. My question is here: What happens if two or more people are using my site and running the PHP script? Will the server handle it? Will the increasement be saved to the file?

Here is my code (if it helps):

```
<?php

    $clicks = file_get_contents("clicks.txt");
    $clicks++;

        $fp = fopen("clicks.txt", "w+");
        fwrite($fp, $clicks);
        fclose($fp);

//give the count to the user
echo "result: $clicks";

    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using a plain file here? Redis or even MySQL with the query `UPDATE table SET field = field + 1;` are much easier to implement and already handle locking for you.

Comment: Of course! http://redis.io/ http://www.mysql.com/

Comment: Yes, but how do I set up like an online account. I remember a friend had a MySQL server at PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: You don't set up an online account. Most hosting providers have mysql included when you purchase hosting services. Some may even allow you to run Redis.

Comment: Oh ok! I have a hosting site, but the problem is that my parents own it and they do not want to give me the password. So, do I have any other solutions?

Comment: Buy your own hosting? Use free hosting?

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to make a professional site. Then I do not want to add some free hosting in the url or on the page. Is there any other way?

Comment: There is no other free way. Unless you want to host your own server (but it doesn't sound like your quite ready for that). And you'd still have to buy a domain and manage DNS entries. I'd stick with a pay-for hosting plan. I think SO would frown upon me suggesting a company so I won't, but look around and do your research.

Comment: How about the method I have already done... I think it's pretty good in my own opinion. But as many has stated this would give me wrong count or it could get reset or something.

Comment: redis? bit overkill? a simple file with locking is just fine for that purpose.. also somewhat persistent, which redis is not. redis also declares itself as not suitable for data that is required to persist, which in this case, obviously is desired.

Comment: @JoeHopfgartner Redis has persistence if you enable AOF: http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Comment: But my host is only PHPMyAdmin

Comment: So you want to make a "professional" site, but you're getting hosting from your parents and you're not willing to pay for the software you need? The key difference between "professional" and non-professional sites is that professionals put money into the facilities and software they need.

Comment: @Jazz Add to that he didn't even know what was MySQL or if mysql was paying... and he wants to do a pro software... my god, BLOATWARE ahead! His next question will be about how to open and close mysql connection

Comment: This is just something simple for my web page. There is no big deal, but now it is. I just want to keep track of how many people have done something, BUT it is not that important.

Comment: Your parents don't need to give you admin rights to the mysql server. They set up a database for you and give you a user Id to *that* database, which can be restricted in all sorts of ways (e.g., they could give you the right to store data but not to create new tables).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all: This is not the way I would write a click counter.

That said, 100 users hitting your server at the same time (with initial clicks at 0) might result in a recorded number of 1..100 with low (=wrong) values being prominent.

- If you want to count in a text file, lock as in @lanzz's answer and be prepared for a major performance hit - you are effectivly serializing the requests.
- If you want to count in any file, consider SQlite and prepare for a manageable performance hit
- If you just want to count, consider a real DB with a very small performance hit

**EDIT: Implementations**

I created the below implementations for a file counter in a text file, SQLite and MySQL

Please do not flame me for using the `mysql_*()` function family - as allways the code is meant to be instructive, not productive: instructive in the sense of concentrating on the issue at hand, not the surrounding layers.

**counter-file.php:**

```
<?php

//acquire file handle
$fd=fopen('counter.txt','c+b');
if (!$fd) die("Can't acquire file handle");

//lock the file - we must do this BEFORE reading, as not to read an outdated value
if (!flock($fd,LOCK_EX)) die("Can't lock file");

//read and sanitize the counter value
$counter=fgets($fd,10);
if ($counter===false) die("Can't read file");
if (!is_numeric($counter)) {
    flock($fd,LOCK_UN);
    die("Value in file '$counter' is not numeric");
}

//increase counter and reconvert to string
$counter++;
$counter="$counter";

//Write to file
if (!rewind($fd)) {
    flock($fd,LOCK_UN);
    die("Can't rewind file handle");
}
$num=fwrite($fd,$counter);
if ($num!=strlen($counter)) {
    flock($fd,LOCK_UN);
    die("Error writing file");
}

//Unlock the file and close file handle
flock($fd,LOCK_UN);
fclose($fd);

printf ("Counter is now %05d",$counter);
?>
```

**counter-sqlite.php:**

```
<?php

//counter.sqlite3 was created with 
//CREATE TABLE counter (counter NUMERIC)
//INSERT INTO counter VALUES (0)

//Open database
$dsn='sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/counter.sqlite3';
$db=new PDO($dsn);
if (!$db) die("Can't open SQlite database via DBO");

//Make exclusive
$sql="BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION";
if ($db->exec($sql)===false) die("Error starting exclusive transaction");

//Update counter
$sql="UPDATE counter SET counter=counter+1";
if (!$db->exec($sql)) die("Error inserting into database");

//Read value
$sql="SELECT counter FROM counter";
$result=$db->query($sql);
if (!$result) die("Error querying database");
foreach ($result as $row) $counter=$row['counter'];

//Commit
$sql="COMMIT TRANSACTION";
if (!$db->exec($sql)) die("Error committing to database");

//Print result
printf("Counter is now %05d",$counter);

?>
```

**counter-mysql.php:**

```
<?php

//mysql database was created with 
//CREATE TABLE counter (counter INT NOT NULL)
//INSERT INTO counter VALUES (0)

//Open database connection and select database 
$db=mysql_pconnect('127.0.0.1','redacted','redacted');
if (!$db) die("Can't open database");
if (!mysql_select_db('redacted', $db)) die("Can't select database");

//Update counter
$sql="UPDATE counter SET counter=counter+1";
$qry=mysql_query($sql,$db);
if (!$qry) die("Error updating database");

//Read value
$sql="SELECT counter FROM counter";
$qry=mysql_query($sql,$db);
if (!$qry) die("Error reading from database");
$counter=mysql_fetch_array($qry,MYSQL_ASSOC);
if (!$counter) die("Error reading result");

//Print result
printf("Counter is now %05d",$counter['counter']);

?>
```

As for the performance: **I stand corrected.** The SQLite implementation is 100 times slower than the two others - this is because I had to accept, that nothing else than `START EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION` would end a test of `ab -n 1000 -c 50 http://127.0.0.1/stackoverflow/counter/counter-sqlite.php` with 1000 clicks counted.

My recommendation for the OP is to use the MySQL version - it is fast and will reliably save the counter over an OS crash. The file version has nearly the same performance characteristics, but it can quite easily be destroyed by an OS crash.

Comment: How do you think I should do this? I am kinda new to this.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp is a great introduction to using MySQL with PHP

Comment: Also: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Truth You don't seem to have read my updated answer: I explicitly talked about the `mysql_*()` functions and their use for simplicity. You also might have noticed, that I use PDO for SQlite, as the vendor-specific sqlite3-extension is buggy (google for "Database locked"). I do not think, that prepared statements (which I happen to know quite well) are the tool of choice for easy-readability as stated.

Comment: @EugenRieck: You don't **have** to use prepared statements for this simple, non-user-input operation. Just don't use `mysql_*`.

Comment: What exactly did you do to the counter that counted to a text file?

Comment: @user1431627 I bracketed the read **and** write phase in `flock(..,LOCK_EX)` resp `flock(..,LOCK_UN)` to make sure, the complete update is atomic if viewed from outside the script. Using `file_get_contents()` outside of this is dangerous, as it introduces a race window, resulting in real-world missed clicks.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. I noticed - your code dose not work because you said `$clicks++;`, but to count you need to write `$count = $count + 1;`. Have you tried your own code?

Comment: Indeed I have tried the code -  I used the `ab` tool to make sure it behaves correctly with high concurreny. `$counter++` is exactly the same as `$counter=$counter+1`

Comment: @EugenRieck I have this wierd problem: you know bytes.... counted characters and stuff. When I run my click code I can click a lot of times and it can show 1000 bytes (1 kb) for the number 100. The right amout of bytes is 3. That must be a bug. The other bug is that sometimes, somehow, it just says 1. It doses that just randomly. I have no idea of how to fix this code because I have not written it myself and I barley know PHP. Do you know hat might be causing this?

Comment: I am really sorry, I don't understand the problem: What do you mean by "counted characters and stuff."

Comment: When I run the code, the text document get exhessive amount of bytes. Sometimes it just adds the number 1. This is really hard to debug.

Comment: What is the text in the text file after it gets so long?

Comment: Like I said... when I reach 100 it says the file size is one kb? There is just the number 100 in the document when it get's to 1 kb.

Comment: If the **content** of the file is OK, ignore the **size**. Most likely you are seeing an artifact of the file lock - if you use Windows, this is guaranteed to happen. Stop the requests, then right-click and chose properties. You now ill see the (correct) file size.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I use a Mac, so yeah. But the problem with it adding 1 instead of increasing by one is wierd.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for the server to handle it by itself. You need to implement file locking yourself. [Reference.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

Comment: @user1431627, you really need to read the flock user comments carefully, and in particular the fine details are very different for LAMP stacks and Windows ones.  Also many shared hosting services use a frontend LAMP farm with the user directory served off an NFS file service which again brings its own wrinkles.  By far the most straightforward way of doing this is to use a small table in a D/B, e.g. MySQL, to hold the counter and here updates are atomic.

Answer (score 2):

The code below will implement your code, but with file locking.
When a file can not be locked it will wait for half a second and try again.

```
<?php

    $clicks = file_get_contents("clicks.txt");
    $clicks++;

    $fp = fopen("clicks.txt", "w+");

    while ( !flock($fp, LOCK_EX) ) {    
        usleep(500000); // Delay half a second
    }

    fwrite($fp, $clicks);
    fclose($fp);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);

    //give the count to the user
    echo "result: $clicks";

?>
```

Comment: Not likely. Only when there are 2 concurrent connections at the exact same microsecond, the 2nd request would get half a second delay and try again. Worst case scenario would be when the file would be locked by some bad script indefinatly, which would cause this bit of script to run into max_execution time. You could catch this error by adding a count to your while loop and simply not loggin anything if no lock could be obtained within say 10 attempts.

Comment: Ah, that sounds nice. They guy who helped me with this code wrote it to count and show it at the same time. How do you do you rewrite it so on one page it counts (without showing count to user) and one where you can see the stats?

Comment: If you have a page where you only want to read the file, you can use the same code, but remove th while loop with the flock (the entire block, including the usleep) and remove the flock($fp, LOCK_UN) at the end. For reading you dont need a lock. (little mistake in my original script btw. I have editet my response: the last flock had to be "flock($fp, LOCK_UN) instead of flock($fp, LOCK_EX).. the correct version unlocks the file at that point.)

Comment: Yes, that would be fine for reading. Read actions dont need a lock on the file.

Comment: I still must say i concur with the average sentiment of the other replies though, using a file as a page counter probably isn't your best option (im just answering your quest instead of coming up with alternatives.) It would be much easier -and- much more convenient to add google analytics code, which for your code isnt more word then adding a piece of javascript code to yours source. Ofcourse this does mean your website's visitors would have to have access to the global internet, so google analytics is no option for an intranet.

Comment: Good of you to notice, no w+ is write/append, my mistake. You should use "r" for reading. And now that we are on the subject, you should also use "w" instead of "w+", considering w+ is append and you want to override your file with the new count. "w" will truncate the file and put the file pointer at the beginning.

Comment: Good! So, if I just change the w+ to r+ in the Pastebin file I sent you the code is good for the page I was just reading to? And this is my XML request thingy http://pastebin.com/g9tKDPFy Will it work on this code or should I change something?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're asking about depends on how the filesystem deals with file i/o, not on PHP itself. Command line scripts would have the same problem (if many of them could run concurrently).

Your code is subject to two race conditions: The disk contents of the file might change between the time you read the file and the time you open it for writing; and it might change between opening for writing and actually writing (flushing) to disk.

The first race condition means you'll be writing a stale value: You increment from 10 to 11, but another thread has already incremented from 10 to 11. You lose a click. The second race condition is more subtle: Because `w+` mode truncates the file, if another thread tries to read just afterwards it will read an empty file, and probably think the count was zero. Finally, it's possible that your file contents will get corrupted. Consider the following sequence of events:

1. thread 1 and thread 2 both read "8" from the file, then open it for writing (truncating it).
2. thread 1 writes "9", but thread 2 is delayed for several milliseconds.
3. in the meantime, thread 3 opens the file, reads "9", and writes "10".
4. finally, thread 2 wakes up, writes "9" to the start of the file and exits.

The result: The file now says "90". This is a real problem whenever data of different lengths is being concurrently written.

**Conclusion:** Don't maintain state in a disk file unless you can reasonably expect that there will be no concurrent access. If visitors are few and far between, no problem. But if your cat video goes viral, your counter will get scrambled and you'll have to ask your parents to check their server logs and count the hits to your page.

Use a database instead: databases are designed to deal with concurrency. Arrange for access to a MySQL database (it does *not* require your parents to give you significant rights on the server). Without even doing that, you can learn your way around databases by installing a database for private use on your computer. If you have a Windows computer, easyPHP is a quick way to help yourself to a private webserver, php, and MySQL with one quick download.

Comment: But file locking would be just fine?

Comment: Yes. **IF** your OS supports it properly (and you use it properly), it will prevent threads from interfering with each other.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you can have two lock problems :

- clicks can reset to 0
- clicks can be erase by an another clicks

You can lock file with the flock method (http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php).
If the lock fail, you need to retry.

Comment: Why would it reset and how do I flock?

Comment: It could be reset because "w+" reset the file, if you read before your write the new number, file_get_contents("clicks.txt") is 0 for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK if the script is executed simultaneously then it will not give you two clicks but just one.
You should better use a database for this operation.

Practically, if you expect low traffic on your website, then this script will do well. But it will fail on higher loads.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I do this?

Comment: Why not use google analytics ? Or install a script like piwik ? (http://piwik.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Most people will desagree with such methods, however you will have problems with concurrent requests. As a solution you can make use of exclusive file locking.

check out the examples: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Comment: But then, some clicks might not get counted?

Comment: no, the other client will wait for the lock to be lifted, then acquire it and proceed as planned - the execution of your code will effectively be paused at that point.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! I thought some clicks did not get to be counted!

Comment: But, how do I flock this file?

Comment: using the function from the link, sorry but i cant explain it better than the manual

Comment: But the manual says else it would give an error. Then, it would not add the count.

Comment: no, this will only happen if you set the 3rd parameter to true.

Comment: Why would they do that if the operation is only delayed?

Comment: File locking to count clicks? What if your file system is not responsive or system load is high? Let all visitors wait for the click to be registered? Use a database, for example MySql or SQlite if you want it file based. If you want to simply register clicks on your website why not use Google Analytics or a similar service?

Comment: Do they have to wait? That is wired. The operations are on wait?

Comment: But can I choose them and show them in another page (Analytics)?

Comment: @HansKerkhof as i said most people will disagree with such methods, however the question the question was not "what is a good way to count clicks" but was very specific with using a file

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to avoid collision is using a log system. You can try this log lib: http://pear.php.net/package/Log/docs/latest/Log/Log.html